# difference between figure window and axes in GUI MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, figure, matlab-guide

To display output images I've used below code

```
function displayResults(filename, header)
    figure('Position',[200 100 700 400], 'MenuBar', 'none', 'Name', header, 'Resize', 'off', 'NumberTitle', 'off');
    % Open 'filename' file... for reading...
    fid = fopen(filename);
    i = 1;                  % Subplot index on the figure...
    while 1
        imagename = fgetl(fid);
        if ~ischar(imagename), break, end       % Meaning: End of File...    
        [x, map] = imread(imagename);
        subplot(2,5,i);
        subimage(x, map);
        xlabel(imagename);
        i = i + 1;
    end
    fclose(fid);
```

This resulted in correct output (http://s1273.photobucket.com/user/Chethan_tv/media/figure_zps326033c2.jpg.html)

where all images are clear.

However, i changed above code to display in my GUI which has 5 axes at output side, code is shown below

```
 function displayResults(filename,hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % Open 'filename' file... for reading...
    fid = fopen(filename);
    for N=6:1:10
        imagename = fgetl(fid);
        if ~ischar(imagename), break, end       % Meaning: End of File...
        x=imread(imagename);
        ax = handles.(sprintf('axes%d', N));
        imshow(x, 'Parent', ax);
        xlabel(ax, imagename);  
    end
    fclose(fid);
```

But this resulted in poor quality output 
(http://s1273.photobucket.com/user/Chethan_tv/media/fig_zpsa48de802.jpg.html?so‌​rt=3&o=0)

What happened to image quality? any appropriate answer is appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you are working with indexed images.

That different behavior is actually in your code, because in first case you display your images with `subimage` function and provide colormap to it (`subimage(x, map);` in your code). In second case you use `imshow` function and do not provide colormap to it (`imshow(x);` in your code), so you display color indices instead of actual colors.

The two functions, `subimage` and `imshow` handle colormaps in indexed images differently, see manual for that.
Try this example too see all the things in one place

```
fn          = 'peppers.png';

rgb         = imread(fn); % This is RGB image
NR          = 2;
NC          = 3;
NI          = NR * NC;
CMapStep    = 12;


figure('Position',[200 100 800 600], 'MenuBar', 'none' );
hAxes = zeros(NI,1);

% displaying original images using subimge
MsgStr = 'subimage(x, map)';
for k=1:NI
    % convert it to indexed image so each image has different number of colors in its colormap
    [x, map] = rgb2ind(rgb,k*CMapStep);
    hAxes(k)    = subplot(NR,NC,k);    % store axes handles for later
    subimage(x, map);
    title(hAxes(k), sprintf('%s: image #%d',MsgStr,k) );
    drawnow;
    pause(1);
end

% displaying original images WITHOUT colormap using imshow
MsgStr = 'imshow(x)';
for k=1:NI
    % convert it to indexed image so each image has different number of colors in its colormap
    [x, map] = rgb2ind(rgb,k*CMapStep);
    imshow(x, 'Parent',hAxes(k) );
    title(hAxes(k), sprintf('%s: image #%d',MsgStr,k) );
    drawnow;
    pause(1);
end

% displaying original images WITH colormap using imshow
MsgStr = 'imshow(x,cmap)';
for k=1:NI
    % convert it to indexed image so each image has different number of colors in its colormap
    [x, map]    = rgb2ind(rgb,k*CMapStep);
    imshow(x,map, 'Parent',hAxes(k) );
    title(hAxes(k), sprintf('%s: image #%d',MsgStr,k) );
    drawnow;
    pause(1);
end
```

As a solution of your problem, you should stick to the same way of displaying your images everywhere or convert them to RGB images to avoid colormap-related issues.

Comment: Sorry,a small mistake. I've used `image(x, 'Parent', ax);` and not `imshow(x, 'Parent', ax);`. . . even though i'm getting poor quality images.

Comment: Can you provide output of `imfinfo('YorImageFileName.Ext')`?

Comment: function `imfinfo` do not display image it just returns a structure, sorry can u give an example of how to use this? where i can use this in my code?

Comment: Im curious about `Format`, `BitDepth`, and `ColorType` fields of the problematic image

Comment: All images are bitmap type. For my CBIR code i need bitmap image of bit depth 8. So using photoshop software i created these images and my database is full of this type of images.

In photoshop: image>mode>indexed color and 8-bit/channel, finally i saved it as .bmp format

Comment: Anyways finally i got good clarity output. simply i changed final image to RGB, then i displayed

    `[x,map]=imread(imagename);`
        `rgb=ind2rgb(x,map);`
        `ax = handles.(sprintf('axes%d', N));`
        `hold(ax, 'off');`
        `image(rgb, 'Parent', ax);`
Thank you for your guidance.